# How does python pass dataframes in and out of functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I started learning python and pandas recently.  I have a script that works just fine with no warnings or errors.  As I'm getting ready to expand on it's capabilities I learned that best practices call for breaking the code out into functions. I divided it out and it runs; however, I get a lot of settingwithcopywarning messages for pretty much every line of code where I'm working with dataframes inside the function.  The structure/syntax is no different from the version of the script without functions that works without issue.  What's python doing with passing the dataframes in and out of the function that this change is causing problems?

This is where the dfStats dataframe and writerStats is defined.  It's pulling data from a web hook.

```
dfStats, writerStats = downloaddata(StatsUrl, "Data.xlsx")
```

This is the function call of interest for an example

```
dfStats = statsprocess(dfStats, writerStats)
```

This is a condensed version of the function as an example.  There's a bit too much in here to generalize away from company information to leave it all in.

```
def statsprocess(df, writer):
    tic = time.perf_counter()
    # Removes summary line of data from the data pull
    df = df[df.DAY != "Total"]
    # Some lines in this column have leading information that I want to remove.
    # The rest of the data is a combination of numbers and _
    df["DATACOLUMN"] = df["DATACOLUMN"].str.replace("123456_", "")
    
    # A lot more stuff happens here to process the dataframe further with the same warnings.

    # Writes current status of the data processing to the xlsx file
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Process Step 1", index=False)
    toc = time.perf_counter()
    print("        Elapsed time:", toc - tic)
    return df
```

I'm not looking for anything to suppress the warnings.  I want to understand why it's behaving differently within a function vs before when it was outside the function. And of course how best to go about fixing these warnings.

Comment: It sounds like these warnings are coming from your IDE, not Python. You should add type annotations so it knows these are pandas dataframes.

Comment: It seems like the settingwithcopywarning is a fairly common warning for dataframes.  I know it shows up in pycharm, which is what I'm using right now. When I was messing around a while ago, I don't think I've seen it come through in Jupyter notebooks.  Either way it's a valid issue.  The results output of the script I broke out into functions is not the same as the output of the script without functions.  So it's definitely treating these differently.

Comment: I'm not a pandas expert, but I'm pretty sure that `df = df[df.DAY != "Total"]` makes a new dataframe. Once you've done that, it's safe to modify the df in place for the rest of the function, since `df` no longer references the original.

Comment: Can you post the two versions of the code and explain the different results you're getting?

Comment: The `df = df[df.DAY != "Total"]` is supposed to just remove that one line from the dataframe rather than create a new dataframe. And if that were the case, it shouldn't have caused the issues ongoing.  The script version that works has the same commands in the same order of operations except it's all done on dfStats since it isn't getting passed into a function.  The scripts are about 300 lines each, and contain company information I can't share/remove.  Essentially it takes data on a collection of items with various values and breaks it down to find an unused range of values.

Comment: It's not removing the row in place. It's returning a new df without the row, then assigning it to the variable. Can you reduce your code to a simpler example that still exhibits the same symptom? We don't need all 300 lines.